# lib firebase_core no flutter quando buildo para ios da erro de Error: To set up CocoaPods for ARM macOS, run: arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Estou buildando um app feito em Flutter para ios usando um MacOs Air chip M1 mas toda vez que eu instalo alguma lib do Firebase como firebase_core, firebase_auth ou até mesmo a libe do google_fonts eu tomo esse erro ao tentar buildar no ios, obs para android builda normal.
[image: log do erro]

meu pubSpec.yml ta assim

[image: pubSpec.yml]

se alguém souber de alguma solução para esse problema fico muito grato.

Comment: Você colocou uma imagem do seu código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Veja [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/137387) e [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/3635)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você provavelmente tentou executar esse comando que ele retorna:

`arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi`

Se mesmo assim não resolveu, tente desta forma:

**1 -** Instale o Homebrew - https://brew.sh

**2 -** Instale o Ruby via Homebrew - `brew install ruby`

(OPCIONAL)

Por algum motivo num Mac da empresa foi necessário instalar/atualizar o Ruby, mas você pode estar pulando este passo e talvez ainda funcione.

**3 -** Instale os packages que não estavam funcionando pelo brew:

```
brew install libffi;

brew install cocoapods;
```

E pronto, é só fechar e abrir o terminal.

Caso não funcione, também peguei na comunidade da Flutterando esse guia, talvez te ajude:

https://medium.com/codex/simple-way-to-use-cocoapods-on-m1-ac9e22cf7e1c

Espero ter ajudado.